# solving equation with variable on both sides

Tags: roots, transcendental-equations

Is there a way to solve the following equation for $v_n^2$? I am working through a problem and I feel like there should be a way to solve it, but I am not sure how to do it:

$$v_n^2-(1+\eta)=-i\omega_n+\frac{i\omega_n}{\gamma_sv_n^2}$$

$$v_n^4+v_n^2 (i\omega_n-1-\eta)-\frac{i\omega_n}{\gamma_s}=0$$

Comment: If you multiply both sides by $\nu_n^2$ and then collect all the terms on one side, the result is a quadratic equation in $\nu_n^2$.

Comment: @carmichael561 Does my new equation look ok? How would I solve for it thought?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: just treat it like x^2+x+a=0?

Comment: Yes, just use the quadratic formula.